# Buffers in Node

Tags: node.js, byte

Consider following Node code

```
const bufA = Buffer.from('tést');
```

bufA :

<Buffer 74 c3 a9 73 74>

Why four characters in input translated to 5 hexadecimal bytes ?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `Buffer.from(string)`, a couple of things happen:

- The encoding is defaulted to `utf-8`
- The JS string, which is internally stored as an array of UCS-2 characters, is encoded into UTF-8

In UTF-8, `é` is a multi-byte character, like most accented characters from Latin scripts. Here's more information on how the character is encoded in different systems: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm

As you can see, the UTF-8 representation of this character is `0xC3 0xA9`, which corresponds to the second and third bytes `c3 a9` in your Buffer.

This also means that, when decoding Buffers (e.g. when concatenating data coming in from a Stream), some characters may fall on the buffer boundary and it may be impossible to decode the string until you have the remainder of the character (0xC3 on its own would be invalid). This is why code examples you find on the Web which do:

```js
let result = '';
stream.on('data', function(buf) {
  // BUG! Does not account for multi-byte characters.
  result += buf.toString();
});
```

are almost always wrong - unless the Stream is already set up for handling encoding itself (then, you'll get strings, not buffers, when reading).